# Descaling a top loading washing machine without a built in heater

Tags: washing-machine

I have an 8 year old top loading washing machine thats never been descaled. It is used with hard water (TDS: about 500 mg/L).

The machine does not have a built in heater. Most descaling solutions seem to require running a wash cycle with max heat and use of the descaler instead of the detergent.

Is it OK to run a descaling cycle in my machine by using a bucket to fill hot water during the wash cycle? Will I need to use hot water for the rinse cycle as well (after using the descaler)?v

Comment: Are you sure you need to descale this washing machine? Usually the scale is deposited when water is heated.

Comment: @JimStewart , I noticed a lot of white deposits on the inside and around the machine's lint filter which have started to break off and result in white flakes on washed clothes. The deposits have a somewhat soft\creamy top layer and are rock hard under the top later (scraping them with a screwdriver barely has any impact).. I figured they are hard water deposits

Answer (score 1):

I think using a bucket of hot water would be fine, just don't use water over 60 C (140 F). In my experience descaling a tea kettle with white vinegar length of time is a factor. You might pour in the descaling solution and let it sit for an hour or two before you start the cycle.

I do not think you need hot water for the rinse.